# Find the next number

Tags: pattern, missing-digits

"I will, of course, kill you if you don't answer. But that's a given, isn't it?" The Enemy says. "So come, Zero, and show me your legendary brain."

$2.828,\quad5.196,\quad11.180,\quad18.520,\quad x$

What is $x$?

C2L, Part 1.

Comment: What is "C2L, Part 1" ?

Comment: @Rubio Part 1 of a series of puzzles I'm going to give.

Comment: @Buddha you should probably cite your source, which seems to also be the TORN forums: https://www.torn.com/forums.php#!p=threads&f=13&t=16018569&b=0&a=0

Comment: This question does not appear to be about creation and solving of puzzles, within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> $36.482$ or $36.483$ depending on whether the numbers are truncated or rounded at 3 decimals.

Explanation:

> The numbers are $2 \sqrt{2}$, $3 \sqrt{3}$, $5 \sqrt{5}$, $7 \sqrt{7}$ where $2$, $3$, $5$, $7$ are successive primes. The next prime is $11$ to give $11 \sqrt{11}=36.4828726...$.

Comment: How do you find this answer? I mean I have no idea how a person can think like this?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson I guess it's because it has to follow *some* fixed rule that you can try out. Also, prime numbers are always popular. So you could try different combinations of prime numbers, once you found out how the first number came to be. Another possibility is, that you actually *know* what $2.828$ is because you have used it at school, at work etc. and start working your way up from there. For instance, I work as a developer and $\sqrt{2}=1.414$ appears quite often in my tasks, so it's useful to remember the decimal value. Then you can immediately see the connection to $2.828$.

Comment: Yes, for me $2.828$ was a dead give-away. On a hunch I then divided the next number by $3$, recognised the result, and the rest followed.